# What does the phrase "throw someone back on his wit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's from an article at the [economist.com](http://www.economist.com/news/christmas/21568696-behind-row-over-bunch-pacific-rocks-lies-sad-magical-history-okinawa-narrative), and it's in the 2nd line of the 17th paragraph(the paragraph right above the 3rd image).

> Like Holland or Portugal, it was a country whose poverty of natural resources **threw the people back on their wits**.

Does it mean “leave the people on their own”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly.  It means they have to rely not on mineral wealth and other accidents of geography,  but rather on their own ingenuity and inspiration: products of their minds not products of their lands.  This can, of course, include hard work and clever trading strategies, both of which those two nations were well-known for in their day.